# Charting in Gtk / Gtk#

Tags: c#, gtk#

i would like to create a simple charting system for stock in Gtk# (and C#), with the possibilities to draw inside it. 
I don't know where to start: it's best to start from scratch ? 
Or using something pre-made ?
Is it best to use Cairo ? Or System.Drawing ?
Are there some piece of code i can reuse ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Medsphere has some custom gtk# widgets and amongst them is a Graph, have a look [here](http://medsphere.org/community/project/medsphere-widgets) for the overview and [here](http://medsphere.org/docs/DOC-1659) for the Graph documentation.

Comment: Where can i find documentation for Graph ? I can't find it ... !

Comment: I don't know if there is a lot more documentation, but I think you can download the source and browse through some examples

Answer (score 0):

You can try 
[nplot](http://netcontrols.org/nplot/wiki/) :

> NPlot includes controls for Windows.Forms, ASP.NET and a class for creating Bitmaps. A GTK# control is also available.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same questions some time ago, and though it is certainly possible to use third party solutions, I researched how to do it myself, finally determining [Mono's Cairo#](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cairo/) was the way to go. It is possible to use the graphics primitives in **Gdk.Window**, but that seems to be obsolete.

About `System.Drawing`, that would be suitable for [charting in Windows Forms](https://github.com/baltasarq/WinFormsDemo).

I even developed a [demo about charting in Gtk#](https://github.com/baltasarq/GtkSharpDemo) in the process.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -6):

if you want to use free charts- use [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c)

don't forget to vote up or mark as answer...